# Why is the execution order of my modules different than expected?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using Babel to compile some ES6 JavaScript down to ES5. I am having some trouble with my code because my modules are being evaluated in an undefined order.

Let's say I have a modules:

```
// a.js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = window.randomProperty;
    console.log("Prop " + this.prop);
  }
}

const a = new A();
export default a;
```

This module relies on `window.randomProperty` to be set before it can instantiate itself.

Now I have a main file:

```
// main.js
import "babel-polyfill"; // Not sure if this is relevant

window.randomProperty = function() { return "hi"; };
console.log("randomProperty set");   

import A from "a";
```

The console output of this is:

```
Prop undefined
randomProperty set
```

How can I have the code execute in the correct order?

Comment: Never use `class`es for singletons! Never export single instances! Use a simple object literal.

Answer (score 1):

import statements are hoisted, so imports are loaded before your code is executed. To execute it in order you want, you should use other module loader such as using `require`.

```
const A = require("a");
```

Comment: Is there any way to control the execution order? For instance, what if I put `window.randomProperty = "hi";` into a module and added `import "the-new-module";` right after `import "babel-polyfill"`?

Comment: @Max Depending on order in which are import statements loaded is not good design pattern in your application (imho). Your modules should do simple things and not modify global state

Comment: I need to set `document.domain` to allow my AJAX calls to bypass CORS when the calls go to subdomains. I don't see a way to make this work without modifying global state.

Comment: @Max I am not telling to no use global state, but maintain it carefully (e.g. initialize it in one place in main.js)

Comment: I guess that's my question, how to do that? I'm using imports everywhere in my code, so it isn't really realistic to switch to `require`. It seems there should be some way to control execution order.

Answer (score 1):

Imports are loaded (and executed, unless cyclic) before the module is executed statically. In your case, `a.js` will be loaded before `main.js` is executed.

If you have dependencies, you should declare them explicitly:

```
// random_prop.js
window.randomProperty = function() { return "hi"; };
console.log("randomProperty set");
```

```
// a.js
import "random_prop";
const a = {
    prop: window.randomProperty;
}
console.log("Prop " + a.prop);
export {a as default}
```

```
// main.js
import "babel-polyfill"; // Not sure if this is relevant
import a from "a";
console.log(a.prop);
```

Of course, you could also `import` the random_prop.js in main.js before a.js, and it would work in this simple setting, but I would not recommend relying on side effects like that.

Comment: Is the execution order of imported modules defined anywhere? I am trying to set `document.domain`, and it feels really incorrect for random modules to produce global state changes. In this very particular case it seems better to modify the global state in exactly one place, namely the main js file. I say this because one could theoretically use this module without wanting to modify `document.domain`.

Comment: The execution order of modules is defined by the directed graph of dependencies and the entry point. Other than that, module loaders can do whatever they want. It is indeed better to do one thing in only one place, which is what modules are made for. In my solution, this place is the `random_prop.js` module, and everyone who needs that state change should import that module.

Comment: The other solution is to defer the execution of the things in module `a.js` by wrapping it in a function and exporting that. You will be able to use it multiple times, and in different global states. See Bobby Matsons answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in where you instantiate `A`, try doing it in `main.js`. Check this out:

```
// a.js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = window.randomProperty;
    console.log("Prop " + this.prop);
  }
}

// do not instantiate here
// const a = new A();
export default a;
```

Just make sure you create the object here:

```
// main.js
import A from "a";

window.randomProperty = function() { return "hi"; };
console.log("randomProperty set");

const a = new A();
```

The reason is, when you import a module, it will invoke any methods that are not tied to a function or class definition.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "*when you import a module, it will invoke any methods that are not tied to a function or class definition*" - what? Nope.

Comment: Apologies, I must be missing something. When you `import`, it executes the body of the module after statically analyzing and loading them. So if you are invoking any functions within the file being loaded (without defining any functions or classes), `import` will execute them, no?

Comment: I believe the modules get executed once and then the exported values are returned multiple times (once for each `import` statement).

Comment: @BobbyMatson: Ah, I see what you mean now, the terminology was confusing. It sounded as if methods were invoked without a call statement anywhere.